# Podio file attached to item cannot be downloaded

Tags: node.js, podio

I have an issue trying to download files attached to Podio items:

```
podio.request('get', '/file/{file_id}/raw').then(console.log);
```

The above program displays:

```
{}
```

This is a JSON stringified empty object (instead of raw file content).

Details:

- The above file can be accessed with its URL when logged in
- The above code is run after proper authentication
- It actually works when using a `file_id` from an image field of the item, but not from a file attachment (pdf files in my case).
- When using API endpoint `/item/app/{app_id}/filter` to get a list of items, the property `file_count` is set, but not `files`. I have to request `/item/{item_id}` individually to get the `files` property included in the response, not sure why.

**Question: Do you know what is the issue, and how I can download raw attached files?**

EDIT: aditionnal info

If I request a single file metadata using the folowing command:

```
podio.request('get', '/file/1234').then(console.log);
```

I get a file JSON object which includes many fields, but *not* the file content :

```
{
  ...
  link: 'https://files.podio.com/1234',
  file_id: 1234,
  ...
}
```

As stated in my comment to @stengaard, if I try to request the API for the above link, here is the response :

```
{ [PodioNotFoundError: [object Object]]
  message:
   { error_parameters: {},
     error_detail: null,
     error_propagate: false,
     request:
      { url: 'http://api.podio.com/1234',
        query_string: '',
        method: 'GET' },
     error_description: 'No matching operation could be found. The path \'/1234\' was not found..',
     error: 'not_found' },
  status: 404,
  url: 'https://api.podio.com:443/1234',
  name: 'PodioNotFoundError' }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `GET /file/{file_id}/raw` endpoint you need an API key with elevated trust levels.

Instead use `GET /file/{file_id}` endpoint. That contains a `link` attribute (a URL) you should follow to get the file content.

The `link` attribute will look like: `https://files.podio.com/{file_id}`. To fetch the file do `https://files.podio.com/{file_id}?oauth_token={oauth_token}`. Where the OAuth token is the same as the one used to `GET /file/{file_id}`. If you know the file ID (e.g. from a `GET /item/{item_id}` you can skip the `GET /file/{file_id}` and contact `files.podio.com` directly. (Note: You can also set the `Authorization: OAuth2 {oauth_token}` header in your HTTP request if you don't like passing the auth token in a URL paramter.)

For an example on how to use it see https://github.com/podio/podio-js/blob/master/lib/general.js#L11

Typically in the JS client, if you use `podio` as your Podio API object, the OAuth token would be located there:

```
podio.authObject.accessToken
```

So to get the raw content of the file in nodejs:

```
var url = 'https://files.podio.com/'+file_id+'?oauth_token='+podio.authObject.accessToken;
request(url, function (err, fileContent) {
    // use fileContent here, write to a file, etc...
});
```

Comment: This does not work: the link cannot be called by a program, it needs human interaction for authentication. I need a way to download the file programmatically, hence the use of the API. As stated in my question, `/file/{fileId}/raw` works for image fields - which are also files - but not files attached to items.

Comment: See my updated answer about the JSON answer when requesting the `link` via the API

Comment: Sorry - you need to supply your `oauth_token` as a parameter. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the details, it works! When using `podio` as podio API object, the OAuth token is located there: `podio.authObject.accessToken`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your request has an error.
please try the below method and get raw file content from its response.

```
podio.request('get', '/file/{file_id}').then(console.log);
```

**FYI**, we couldn't get the files by filtering the items. we need to request `/item/{item_id}` individually to get the files property as you said.

Comment: Hi @Mûhámmàd, thanks for your answer. It does not work. I have updated my answer to show why. (the request you propose gets the file metadata, not the actual file content)